# fetching string data as Json data

Tags: mysql, json, angularjs

On submission I am storing data in the Json format in the database.
But when I am fetching the database the Json is fetched  in the string format as the datatype is set as TEXT.

I want to retrieve some of the Json objects like only companyName from this Json.

```
{
deleted: false,
Id: 1,
Request: "{"companyName":"ABCD","address":"sd"}",
Uuid: "7f000101-4fdf-160d-814f-dfa60dc80000",
isDeleted: false,
modifiedAt: 1442566841000,
status: 4
}
```

But when I am using `{{info.Request}}` the whole Request object is fetched and I only want `companyName`. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to store the data correctly on the database and fetch it as a full JSON object, so then you don't have to parse it with Angular or whatever software you will use to render.

If you still can't do that, then from the Front End side (not recommended):

1. Convert the string to JSON on the controller or another place:

   ```
   $scope.parseStringToJSON = function(value) {
     return JSON.parse(value);
   };
   ```
2. Now use the object on the view:

   ```
   <p>{{parseStringToJSON(info.Request).companyName}}</p>
   ```